# How to make make events listen over node.js files?

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io, event-handling

I am trying to make sure an event emitted in one node.js file is heard by the other.

arduino.js

```
eventEmitter.emit('eventcall');
```

main.js

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('eventcall', hidemainscreen);
```

anyways its not hearing the call. My guess is because im using arduino events in one module and socket in another. How do i fix this? How do i use the same socket in main to pick up the event in arduino.js

Comment: if `hidemainscreen` is a function you should separate them with , `socket.on('eventcall',hidemainscreen);`

Comment: thanks, i just edited the question

Comment: What is the `eventEmitter` object you have in your first file?  Where did it come from?  In order to "hear" an emitted event, you have to be listening to the "exact same" eventEmitter object that emitted the event - the same actual object, not just the same type of object.

Comment: i know the object is different, im wondering how to make it the same.